# Can I has RSS link on Tagged Questions and Tag Wiki pages?

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

Like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Now, the only place where I know I can find the RSS for a tag is in the tag's popup.

Comment: What do you need an RSS feed for a tag wiki for? You might want to take a look at [this tool](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com) - it can access tagged questions and tag wikis.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Its not for the wiki, its for the tag.

Comment: So you need an RSS feed of new questions for a certain tag?

Comment: @Geo Not sure why this is not blatantly clear to you.  Let me suggest this--go forth and bring me back the link to the rss feed for the [c#] tag so that I may see all new questions posted that have the C# tag in my RSS reader.  Once you have given up, please come back and re-read this feature request and understand why I want to make it easy to get the feed for a tag.

Comment: Ah... so this isn't a request for the feed - it's a request for the feed to be *more obvious*. Right?

Comment: Maybe I've been here too long, but it was intuitive for me to hover over the tag in the tags page and find the rss link in the css thingy that slides out.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Hells bells.

Comment: not following why we need to add this in the top, when it is already at the bottom AND in the page header

Comment: [free-hand narwhal drawing](http://www.studio30seven.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/character-design/narwhal_tattoo4.jpg) - "[like a sir](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/feel-like-a-sir)".   I take no credit for the image ;)

Comment: @Lix: Oh God! Does that narwhal have a weasel-head growing out of it's shoulder with a sword through?!

Comment: @Bobby, sadly - yes. What you say is true.  Ever since the release of Ubuntu 11.4 I have had an aversion to narwhals...  The new rage for all the *cool* kids however is a [dosecorn](http://www.greatdreams.com/unicorn.gif)!

Comment: @Lix I actually like 11.04, except for that annoying redraw bug...it's Unity and Gnome3 which give me the creeps. ;) And, yeah, dosecorn sounds cool, we should have one of those sponsoring question bans or something.

Comment: I'm with you - Unity+Gnome3 was a deal breaker for me...  I've gone back to 10.4 LTS :P Putting it off till 2013 ^_^

Comment: When the hell did this become unix and linux chat?